# Elm "implies" function

Tags: elm

I'm looking for an Elm function that does the following:

```
if e then
  Just a
else
  Nothing
```

For example, I am looking for an operator `(=>) : Bool -> a -> Maybe a` (binary function is fine also) that can be used like this

```
(x == 42) => "yes"
```

and will return `Just "yes"` if `x == 42` and `Nothing` otherwise.

Clearly, I can use the `if-then-else` to accomplish the same thing, but I curious if such a function already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Elm Fancy Search](http://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/) tool is great for this kind of search. You can type in a function signature or name and see where it is used across all packages listed on [package.elm-lang.org](http://package.elm-lang.org/).

At the current time, [that function signature](http://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/?q=Bool%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20Maybe%20a) exists in two packages under the function name `when`:

1. [krisajenkins/elm-exts/27.4.0: Exts.Maybe.when](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/elm-exts/27.4.0/Exts-Maybe#when): When `test` returns true, return `Just value`, otherwise return `Nothing`.
2. [Gizra/elm-essentials/1.2.0: Gizra.Maybe.when](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Gizra/elm-essentials/1.2.0/Gizra-Maybe#when): Create a `Just a` if condition is `True`, otherwise `Nothing`

Comment: I was hoping for a Hoogle-like engine. Thanks.